# How to display error on object(rather than field) when I use hibernate validator?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

When I debug my application I see following BindingResult:
[image]

As you can see I have 3 violations:

1. beginDate field
2. newEmail field
3. campaignBeanDto object

to display the first two I can type something like this:

```
  <form:errors cssClass="error"  path="beginDate"/>
  <form:errors cssClass="error"  path="newEmail"/>
```

How to display third error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
<form:errors cssClass="error"  path=""/>
```